# UWSGI with anaconda

Tags: uwsgi

i have tried to install this command "pip install uwsgi" in anaconda env but i got this error

```
 *** error linking uWSGI ***
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uwsgi
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for uwsgi did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [151 lines of output]
```

============

```
*** error linking uWSGI ***
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> uwsgi

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

could someone help me on this error in advance thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem, I solved it by running these commands before installing the requirements

```
conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi 
pip install -r requirements.txt
```